# Angular 6: Router parameter not working with service

Tags: angular

I'm new in angular and I'm trying to navigate the data which comes from API. Routing is working fine It goes to its respective component but not getting the data in address bar. And it's not showing any error in console.
[image] [image]

### app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GithubProfileComponent } from './components/section-ten/github-profile/github-profile.component';
import { SectionTenComponent } from './components/section-ten/section-ten.component';
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from './components/not-found-page/not-found-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [  
  {path : 'section-ten/:id', component: GithubProfileComponent},
  {path : 'section-ten', component: SectionTenComponent}, 
  {path : '', component: SectionTenComponent}, // Set Home page 
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundPageComponent } // Not found page
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [
  SectionTenComponent,
  NotFoundPageComponent,
  GithubProfileComponent
]
```

Service from where I,m getting data.

### hamedani-followers.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HamedaniFollowersService {
  gitHubUrl = 'https://api.github.com/users/mosh-hamedani/followers';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFollowers(){
    return this.http.get(this.gitHubUrl)
  }

}
```

This my parent component. Which containing that 'a' tag (Click event).

### section-ten.component.html

```
<div class="cont">
  <h3>Routing</h3>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let hamedaniFollower of hamedaniFollowers | slice:0:5; let i=index">
      <div class="img_cont">
        <img [src]="hamedaniFollower.avatar_url" />
      </div>
      <div class="text_cont">
        <h4>{{hamedaniFollower.login}}</h4>
        <h5><a [routerLink]="['/section-ten', 'hamedaniFollower.id']">{{hamedaniFollower.url}}</a></h5>
      </div>      
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Parent component file.

### section-ten.component.ts.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HamedaniFollowersService } from './../../services/hamedani-followers.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'section-ten',
  templateUrl: './section-ten.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./section-ten.component.scss']
})
export class SectionTenComponent implements OnInit {
  hamedaniFollowers : any;

  constructor(private service: HamedaniFollowersService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getFollowers()
    .subscribe( members => this.hamedaniFollowers = members );    
  }

}
```

Child component file from where I'm trying to get ID.

### github-profile.component.ts (Child component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-github-profile',
  templateUrl: './github-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./github-profile.component.scss']
})
export class GithubProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private Routes: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.Routes.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      let id = +params.get('id');
      console.log(params.get('id'));
     })
  }

}
```

Comment: remove quotes around 'hamedaniFollower.id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
<h5><a [routerLink]="['/section-ten', 'hamedaniFollower.id']">{{hamedaniFollower.url}}</a></h5>
```

It has to be:

```
<h5><a [routerLink]="['/section-ten', hamedaniFollower.id]">{{hamedaniFollower.url}}</a></h5>
```

Or you just say that `hamedaniFollower.id` is a normal string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

you should be passing `hamedaniFollower.id` not the string `'hamedaniFollower.id'` in `section-ten.component.html` file. where you are defining `h5`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer